# creating a url with params, and using them in other gsp page grails groovy

Tags: grails

I would like to dynamically create a link with some parameters to a page where those values would be used:

```
<td><a href="${createLink(controller:'display', action="viewer", params: ['file' : '${stream.file}', 'media' : '${stream.media}'])}">${fieldValue(bean: streamInstance, field: "media")}</a></td>
```

In my `viewer.gsp` I want to be use those values in a link that displays a video stream:

```
<source src="path/to/my/videodir/${media}" type='video/mp4'></source>
```

But I'm not having much success so far :-(. Could someone please help me on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i see a few places where there should be semicolons instead of equals, and single quotes instead of double quotes

```
${createLink(controller:'display', action:'viewer', params:'[file : "${stream.file}", media : "${stream.media}']")}
```

my only other thoughts is that if the stream.file variables don't display their value, then try escaping the double quotes /" and if that doesn't work then try removing the ${} around stream.file and stream.media since they are already inside an EL block

Comment: what is with action='viewer' shouldn't it be action:'viewer'?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

```
<g:set var="myarray" value="[file: stream.file, media: stream.media]" />
<a href="${createLink(controller:'display', action:'viewer', params:myarray)}">
  ${fieldValue(bean: streamInstance, field: "media")}
</a>
```